# Longitudinal analysis of interacted effect nested by group and time with LMER

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, longitudinal

I am conducting analyses of survey data nested by country and year. The respodents surveyed are never the same, but the countries surveyed are repeated.

The data looks something like this, where `y` is the DV, `x` is the IV, `g` is a group variable that I am interested in interacting with the DV `x`. The data is nested by country `co` and by year `t`.

```
dat <- data.frame(y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1),
                  x = c(1, 6, 3, 9, 3, 6, 4, 4, 9, 2, 8, 2, 5, 3, 7),
                  g = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2),
                  t = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0),
                  co = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"))
```

Basically, I want to conduct a longitudinal analysis where `x*g` predicts `y`. Given it's a longitudinal analysis, I think I need to interact the effect with year `t`, correct? Also, I think I need to control for the random effect and slopes of country `co`. So this is what I've done:

```
model1 <- glmer(y ~ x*t*g + (1+x|co) + (1|co), data = dat)

stargazer(model1, type = "text")

===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                                 y             
-----------------------------------------------
x                             -0.390           
                              (0.818)          

t                             -3.317           
                              (6.415)          

g                             -1.971           
                              (3.012)          

x:t                            0.471           
                              (1.218)          

x:g                            0.379           
                              (0.514)          

t:g                            1.566           
                              (4.312)          

x:t:g                         -0.359           
                              (0.798)          

Constant                       5.517           
                              (4.367)          

-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    15             
Log Likelihood                -22.627          
Akaike Inf. Crit.             71.253           
Bayesian Inf. Crit.           80.458           
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to conduct longitudinal analysis like this, so wanted to ask if someone could confirm or correct this. Thanks.

Comment: Try to look here: https://datascienceplus.com/analysing-longitudinal-data-multilevel-growth-models-i/, https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer, https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/78961_fe5b5c6a77f446eca899afbb32bd1dc7.html#hlm-models-and-analyses, https://ase.tufts.edu/gsc/gradresources/guidetomixedmodelsinr/mixed%20model%20guide.html

Comment: You should add `t` as random slope as well. The interaction `x*t` is only required if you're assuming / interested in _different_ time trends for values of `x` or for levels of `g`. A classical example is a group comparison over time (treatment and control group). You'll find good examples in the rpsychologist link posted by DJV.